# Java instantiating a generic type which implements an interface

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

I got a question while studying OOP concept and inner classes in Java.

Let's say there is a class `CarFactory`, and it has `buildCar()` method that returns a `Car`. This factory builds several `Models` that implement a `Car`.

Therefore, I made a `Car` interface and the `Models` implement `Car`.

How can you return a `Car` that is an interface?

I know that I can instantiate a `Model` that implements a Car, but I want to make a general method that returns any `Model` that implements a `Car`.

CarFactory.java

```
public class CarFactory {
  Car buildCar() {
    return new Car();  // ??? I cannot do this 
  }
}
```

Car.java

```
public interface Car {
  abstract class Construct {
    abstract void constructCar();
  }
  void turn();
  void stop();
  void accelerate();
  ...
}
```

ModelExample.java

```
public class ModelExample implements Car {
  static CarFactory factory;

  public ModelExample() {
    this.factory = new CarFactory();
  }

  class Construct extends Car.Construct {
    void constructCar() {
      System.out.println("Model Example constructed");  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Help me understand the question - "How can you return a Car that is an interface?" - You don't, you return something that *implements* the interface, right? -  "I want to make a general method that returns any Model that implements a Car." What is "Model" ? Where is this "general method", how does it know what "Models" exist and how to create them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you cannot initialize interfaces. I suggest you study the Abstract Factory design pattern.

For your case, you would need an interface `AbstractCarFactory`, which contains a method `Car buildCar`. You can then create subclasses of the `AbstractCarFactory` for each type of car.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.